# Update values in join table using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

Given this entity class

```java
@Entity
public class Profile extends Model {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  ...
  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @Cascade(value={CascadeType.ALL})
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
  private Set<Expectation> expectations;
  ...
}
```

the update operation made on the Profile object does not affect the expectations set (mapped on a join table).

I use the following code:

```java
Session dbSession = DBHandler.getDbSession(); // custom static method

Profile profile = (Profile) dbSession.get(Profile.class, id);

Set<Expectation> expectations = new HashSet<Expectation>();
for (Long id : expectationsIds)
  expectations.add((Expectation) dbSession.get(Expectation.class, id));
profile.setExpectations(expectations);

dbSession.beginTransaction();
dbSession.saveOrUpdate(profile);
dbSession.getTransaction().commit();

dbSession.close();
```

Comment: If you are using a join table, don't you need to have the `@JoinTable` on your `@OneToMany` mapping? How does your `Profile` class know where to join them? See the [Hibernate documentation example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-one-to-many-with-join-table)

Comment: A join table (named Profile_Expectation) with the relative foreign keys is generated automatically by hibernate. Do I have to declare the @JoinTable annotation anyway?

Comment: Can you show the code that manipulates the expectations? What do you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: I've added the missing snippet of code. The problem occurs when I perform the update of a Profile entity: I don't see any change in the Profile_Expectations table even if I overwrite the Expectation hash set.